# Configure PHP to use a proxy for curl

Tags: php, curl

I have a very large application that uses multiple curl calls. I want them to be routed through a proxy (due to IP restrictions on destination firewall).

Because of the sheer number of curl calls it is impractical for me to change the `CURLOPT_PROXY` attribute for all.

Is there a way I can configure PHP-cURL to use a default proxy config from somewhere.

Also note I use `/etc/environment` to pass all traffic from my server via the proxy but this setting isn't affecting php-curl for some reason.

I am running this on a Ubuntu 16.04 system with nginx and php5.6.

Comment: Can you not write a script that reads all PHP files that make a cURL call and add a line in  the right spot for CURLOPT_PROXY?

Comment: I agree. Just search for `curl_init()` and append your setting after it.